# Processing Loop

Tags: javascript, processing

```
int objectX = width/2; 
int objectY = height/2; 
int snelheidY = 1; 
int score = 0; 
int richting = 1; 
int positiebal;  
int bal = ellipse(objectX, objectY, 50, 50); 
lost = false;

void setup() { 
    size(400, 400); 
    positiebal = height/2; 
    textSize(12); 
} 

void draw() { 
    background(0, 0, 0); 
    ellipse(positiebal, objectY, 50, 50); 
    if(objectY > 375) 
        snelheidY = -snelheidY; 
    if(objectY<25) 
        snelheidY = -snelheidY; 
    objectY = objectY + snelheidY; 
    text("score = " +score,4,10); 

    if (score < 0)
        {  textSize(20); 
            text("play again",50,50);
            noLoop();
            lost = true;
            textSize = 13;
        }

    }

    void mousePressed() { 
        int distance = dist(200, objectY, mouseX, mouseY); 
        if (distance<=25) 
    //score hoger maken met 1 punt
{ score=score+1; 

    if (snelheidY < 0) 
        { snelheidY = snelheidY -1; } 
    { snelheidY = snelheidY+1; } 
} 
    // score met 1 punt lager maken
    else 
        { score = score - 1;

            if (snelheidY > 1)
                { snelheidY = snelheidY -1; } 


        }  

        if (lost == true)
            { snelheidY = 1;
                score = 0;
                positiebal = height/2;
                richting = 1;
                lost= false; 
                loop();}

            }
```

I made a loop for the whole process to restart after the score<0, but it doesn't work the second time. The first time it works fine, but the second time it just stops the game without showing the restart text and without restarting.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `loop()` and `noLoop()` for this. Instead, store your state in a set of variables, and use those variables to draw each frame. Here's a simple example:

```
boolean start = true;
boolean play = false;
boolean end = false;

void draw() {

  background(0);

  if (start) {
    text("start", 20, 20);
  } else if (play) {
    text("play", 20, 20);
  } else if (end) {
    text("end", 20, 20);
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (start) {
    start = false;
    play = true;
  } else if (play) {
    play = false;
    end = true;
  } else if (end) {
    end = false;
    start = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but we have to solve our problem by using loops, it was part of the project...

Comment: @Beastmaster64 are you sure "solve your problem using loops" means using `loop` and `noLoop()` or might it mean using `for` loops? If you want help then please post a [mcve] instead of your whole project.

Comment: So this is a school project? Also, where are the `loop` and `noLoop` functions?

Comment: @AndersTornblad Please note that this is a [tag:processing] question, and [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java). The `loop()` and `noLoop()` functions are Processing functions.